# Локальное объявление функции с пустой пачкой аргументов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
void declare_and_call(Args... args) {
    // declaration
    ReturnType bar(Args...); // (1) OK
    ReturnType bar(args...); // (2) error: variable or field ‘bar’ declared void

    // function call
    bar(args...);
}

// another .cpp file
// definition
void bar() {

}


int main() {
    declare_and_call<void>();
}
```

Почему второе объявление не является объявлением функции при пустой пачке параметров, а воспринимается как объявление переменной?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение о том, что означает строчка 2, принимается еще на этапе синтаксического анализа, еще при парсинге определения шаблона, еще до того, как будут рассматриваться какие-то специализации шаблона и переданные вами шаблонные аргументы.

Парсер языка видит в строчке 2

```
ReturnType bar(args...);
```

А `args...` - это pack expansion, примененный к *function* parameter pack. Этот вариант ни в коем случае не является объявлением функции уже на синтаксическом уровне: в грамматике языка С++ нет правил вывода, который бы приводили к тому, чтобы список параметров функции состоял из *function* parameter pack expansion. *Template* parameter pack expansion - разрешается, *function* parameter pack expansion - не разрешается.

Вот и все. Решение о том, что второе объявление НЕ является объявлением функции было принято сразу и зафиксировано еще до того, как шаблон начал специализироваться. Поэтому не имеет никакого значения, сколько аргументов и какие аргументы вы передаете в шаблон `declare_and_call`.

---

Обратите внимание, кстати, что именно за счет этого parameter packs дают нам возможность сделать то, что раньше было невозможным - использовать инициализатор `()` в объявлении объекта, не боясь при этом получить объявление функции

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(T... t)
{
    int i(t...);
    // Если расширение пусто, то переменная `i` получает значение `0`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант не приводит объявлению функции, потому что args... разворачивается не в список типов, а в список значений. Это приводит к тому, что объявляется переменная типа ReturnType с именем bar и инициализируется args...

А так как имя bar строкой выше отдано во власть функции, возникает ошибка переопределения имени для новой сущности.

В качестве [примера](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bt9QWhVzoST9c40y) я немного изменил ваш код, убрав объявление функции, чтобы видеть, что второй bar - это переменная:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
void declare_and_call(Args... args) {
    // declaration
    //ReturnType bar(Args...); // (1) OK
    ReturnType bar(args...); // (2) error: variable or field ‘bar’ declared void

    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(bar), ReturnType> << "\n";

    std::cout << bar << "\n";
}

int main() {
    declare_and_call<int, double>(42.5);
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1
> 42
> ```

1 говорит о том тип bar соответствует ReturnType
42 - о том, что 42.5 (вещественное), переданное как аргумент double преобразовалось при инициализации в целое 42.

В случае отсутствия параметров args... судя по всему выраждается в {}. Это надо бы уточнить, но пока не готов ковырять стандарт. А при ReturnType void получается вовсе ошибка инстанцирования, т.к. переменная не может быть void.

Comment: "потому что args... разворачивается не в список типов, а в список значений." Ну так суть вопроса-то именно в том и заключается - почему при **пустом** `args...` не получается объявления функции? Вариант с `42.5` никаких вопросов не вызывает -  с ним все и так ясно.